# web folder release script swap

Tags: web, release-management

I am looking to have three web folders one would serve as a backup and rollback and one for testing new releases.

```
/var/web/project
/var/web/project_test
/var/web/project_backup
```

Say I upload my code to project_test and I'm happy with it.  I'm now ready to release it.  How would I then have a singular command that would..

```
1) Move 'project' into 'project_backup'.  
2) Move 'project_test' into 'project' 
3) Delete whats in backup
```

Comment: You may want to expand on what you mean ( and why you say) singular command as it will frame the sort of answers you will receive. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I would personally upload a folder for each version having them accessible through some sort of rewrite. Production could be managed by a symlink you point to whichever version you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
rm /var/web/project_backup
mv /var/web/project /var/web/project_backup
mv /var/web/project_test /var/web/project
mkdir /var/web/project_test
```

Another way, if you're using a CVS (eg git) is using different branches for different stages, and commiting/fetching from/to a branch you need.